# Laravel Request does not return result

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1

I am using AWS and laravel 5.1.

I have two issues:

- Most of the time API returns the expected result but sometimes server
  doesn't return result for longer time. It might be due to the server
  load(Although we don't have too much load on server).

  Clients wait for few minutes and after that application crashes. Any
  Advice.
- If Client made an API request and before getting result, if device
  loses internet connection. Server has process the data but unable to
  deliver it to the client. how to handle this (Both in get as well as
  post request)

Sample Code for first Part

```
public function psychometricResponses(Request $request)
    {
        $questionId=$request->get('questionId');
        $answerId=$request->get('answerId');
        $from = $request->has('from');
        $userId = $request->has('id') ? $request->get('id') : 0;
        $name = $request->has('name') ? $request->get('name') : '';
        $email = $request->has('email') ? $request->get('email') : '';
        $gender = $request->has('gender') ? $request->get('gender') : '';
        $relationshipStatus = $request->has('relationshipStatus') ? $request->get('relationshipStatus') : '';
        if($userId!=0){
            $status = 1;
            User::where('id',$userId)->update(['status'=>1]);
        }else{
            $status = 0;
        }
        $id = $this->calculatePersonality($questionId, $answerId, $userId, $from, $name, $email, $gender, $relationshipStatus);
        return  json_encode(['code'=>200,'message'=>"success",'response'=>array('personality'=>$this->_getPersonality($id),'psychometricId'=>$id,'status'=>$status)]);    
    }


public function calculatePersonality($questionId, $answerId, $userId, $from, $name, $email, $gender, $relationshipStatus)
    {
        //
        $questionArray = explode(',', $questionId); //arraySize is 60
        $answerArray = explode(',', $answerId);     // //arraySize is 60
        $this->questionAll = $this->_questionAll();
        $personality = array('O'=>0,'C'=>0,'E'=>0,'A'=>0,'N'=>0);
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($answerArray);$i++){
            $type = $this->_getQuestionType($questionArray[$i]);
            if($type=='O'){
                $personality['O'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['O']+1 : $personality['O']-1;
            }else if($type=='OR'){
                $personality['O'] =$answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['O']-1 : $personality['O']+1;
            }else if($type=='C'){
                $personality['C'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['C']+1 : $personality['C']-1;
            }else if($type=='CR'){
                $personality['C'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['C']-1 : $personality['C']+1;
            }else if($type=='E'){
                $personality['E'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['E']+1 : $personality['E']-1;
            }else if($type=='ER'){
                $personality['E'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1'?$personality['E']-1 : $personality['E']+1;
            }else if($type=='A'){
                $personality['A'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['A']+1 : $personality['A']-1;
            }else if($type=='AR'){
                $personality['A'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['A']-1 : $personality['A']+1;
            }else if($type=='N'){
                $personality['N'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1'? $personality['N']+1 : $personality['N']-1;
            }else if($type=='NR'){
                $personality['N'] = $answerArray[$i]=='1' ? $personality['N']-1 : $personality['N']+1;
            }
        }
        $mod = array();
        $mod['O'] = abs($personality['O']);
        $mod['C'] = abs($personality['C']);
        $mod['E'] = abs($personality['E']);
        $mod['A'] = abs($personality['A']);
        $mod['N'] = abs($personality['N']);
        arsort($mod);
        $values = array_keys($mod);
        $pTypeOne = $personality[$values[0]] < 0 ? $values[0].'R' : $values[0];
        $pTypeTwo = $personality[$values[1]] < 0 ? $values[1].'R' : $values[1];
        $pTypeThree = $personality[$values[2]] < 0 ? $values[2].'R' : $values[2];
        $pTypeFour = $personality[$values[3]] < 0 ? $values[3].'R' : $values[3];
        $pTypeFive = $personality[$values[4]] < 0 ? $values[4].'R' : $values[4];
        $psychometricResponse = PsychometricResponse::create(array('typeA'=>$pTypeOne, 'valueA'=>$personality[$values[0]],'typeB'=>$pTypeTwo, 'valueB'=>$personality[$values[1]],
            'typeC'=>$pTypeThree, 'valueC'=>$personality[$values[2]],'typeD'=>$pTypeFour, 'valueD'=>$personality[$values[3]],
        'typeE'=>$pTypeFive, 'valueE'=>$personality[$values[4]],'questionId'=>$questionId,'answerId'=>$answerId, 'userId'=>$userId, 'from'=>$from,'name'=>$name,'email'=>$email, 'gender'=>$gender,'relationshipStatus'=>$relationshipStatus));
        return $psychometricResponse->id;

    }


private function _questionAll(){
        $question = PsychometricQuestion::where('isActive',1)->get(['id','type']);
        $result =array();
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($question);$i++){
            $result[$question[$i]->id] = $question[$i]->type;
        }
        return $result;

    }

    private function _getQuestionType($id){
        return $this->questionAll[$id];
    }

private function _getPersonality($id){
    $personality = PsychometricResponse::where('id',$id)->first(['typeA','typeB','typeC','typeD','typeE','valueA','valueB']);
    $combined = array($personality->typeA,$personality->typeB);
    sort($combined);
    $combinedPersonality = PsychometricResult::where('type',$combined[0]."-".$combined[1])->first(['type','keyword','description','colorCode']); //Table PsychometricResult has 40 rows only.
    $primaryPersonality = PsychometricResult::where('type',$personality->typeA)->first(['type','keyword','description','colorCode']);
    $secondaryPersonality = PsychometricResult::where('type',$personality->typeB)->first(['type','keyword','description','colorCode']);
    $permutation = $this->_getAllPermutation($personality);
    $stylePersonality = PsychometricStyle::whereIn('type',$permutation)->get(['type','aspect','style','description']);
    $primaryPercentage = round(abs($personality->valueA)/(abs($personality->valueA)+abs($personality->valueB)), 2);
    $secondaryPercentage = 1 - $primaryPercentage;
    return array('primaryPersonality'=>$primaryPersonality,'secondaryPersonality'=>$secondaryPersonality,'combinedPersonality'=>$combinedPersonality,
        'styles'=>$stylePersonality,'primaryPercentage'=>$primaryPercentage,'secondaryPercentage'=>$secondaryPercentage);
}

private function _getAllPermutation($personality){
    $combined = array($personality->typeA,$personality->typeB,$personality->typeC,$personality->typeD,$personality->typeE);
    sort($combined);
    $permutation = array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($combined);$i++){
        for($j=$i+1;$j<5;$j++){
            array_push($permutation,$combined[$i]."-".$combined[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $permutation;
}
```

Comment: what Amazon service you are using ?

Comment: I am using AWS EC2-Instance, SES, RDS and S3

Comment: please post some sample code, which is crashing or taking time, so we can do through it